# Can NCover be used to select test cases for NUnit?

Tags: testing, nunit, ncover

What are the best tools for test selection, preferably using NUnit and NCover.  I'd like to be able to take a changelist, or list of changed files, and identify the test cases that are likely to give me test coverage based on previous code coverage data.

Obviously there is a chicken and egg problem here.  Since the code is changed, we need to execute the tests and measure coverage to determine which tests cover the new code.  Assume I have hundreds or thousands of test cases that take hours to execute and I want to only run a handful of tests that are automatically selected for the particular files (or functions) modified.